# Ion-select multiple options but with one exclusive options

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-formly

So I would like to create a ion-select with multiple options but with one option that is exclusive.
Example :
[image]

In this image, if I select Nowhere the other options deselect themselves and if I select Head-front and Eyes the opposite applies : "Nowhere" deselect itself.

I looked into the ion-select doc but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: You will have to listen to the `ionChange` event and add your logic to select/deselect values there.

Comment: as @PankajSati said you have to use `ionChange` event and use disable attributes on your `<ion-select-options [disabled]="selectedId == nowhereId">`